# Datepicker: Disabling dates in the data

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I have a datepicker which enables 3weeks from now(start) up to the rolling 12weeks(end). I would like to add a condition that if the date on that span was already in the data(Spreadsheet) it will also be disabled. See script below:

```
 <script>

   var data = SpreadsheetApp
        .openById('Spreadsheet ID')
        .getSheetByName("VL Request")
        .getDataRange()
        .getValues();  
   var datefiled = [0];
   var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();


      $( function() {
      //enable next week onwards 
    var date = new Date();
    var weekday = date.getDay();
    var daysTillWeekOver = 21 - weekday;
    var enddayofweek = daysTillWeekOver + 5;
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      minDate:daysTillWeekOver,
      maxDate: "3M" + enddayofweek
      });
      } );
</script>
```

I want to add a condition that if the user filed for that date(datefiled) it will be disabled on the datepicker for that user so the user will avoid filing a duplicate on that date.

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding private or confidential information) and include an example of a successful outcome. In this case, would you edit your question to explain where previous used dates are stored and how they can be accessed.

Comment: Here's the sample copy of my spreadsheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lNWsvvBkv-GiVD2QkqYt9ofQB3y7aVsAeWJLOb9lMas/edit?usp=sharing

In VL Request tab I need to compare it if current user(column C) and Date of VL(column F). If it's true the date of VL should be disabled in the current range of enabled dates in the datepicker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Disable Specific Days and Dates Using BeforeShowDay In jQueryUiDatepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327697/how-to-disable-specific-days-and-dates-using-beforeshowday-in-jqueryuidatepicker)

Comment: Not resolved yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "Not resolved yet"?

Comment: You might also look at [How to pass a parameter to html?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30033459/1330560). @ZigMandel's answer includes a detailed example and a gist tutorial about passing parameters.

Comment: I am thinking in creating a for loop to check the dates of VL filed of user in my data then that date will be disabled. However, I am having a hard time to think on how to do it. 

Comment: You can't loop through users if there's no data. Column C of your spreadsheet is empty. You need to populate Column C so you can develop the loop. You've got to explain how you will identify the "current user".

Comment: sorry I just removed the data on column C because they were confidential information but its the users LDAP. You can identify the current user by its LDAP.

Comment: It’s ok to remove private or confidential information. But please replace it with some dummy data. Also, please supply your code that identifies the current user.

Comment: Sample data as been updated. In my code above the identifier of the current user is the userName. var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();

Comment: Argh; here's me thinking that getting the LDAP was a smoke and mirrors kinda-thing.

Answer (score 1):

You want to limit a JQuery datepicker to exclude dates *previously chosen by the user*. This means that the dates to be excluded may vary on each use the script .

The topic [How To Disable Specific Days and Dates Using BeforeShowDay In jQueryUiDatepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46335773/1330560) (props to @Amal) show that the datepicker script requires a simple array of dates. However I found that *every* example showing the use of `BeforeShowDay` assumes that the excluded dates are hard-coded into the script. This is unacceptable in your scenario because of the variability of the user and consequently the dates previously selected by the user.

The following is a complete webapp that takes the spreadsheet data and searches for instances of the username, obtains the relevant VL dates, pushes the dates to an array read by the webapp, and then picked up by the Datepicker and reflected in the browser.

---

**Example of excluded dates**

### [image: Example of excluded dates]

Props to [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58811576/1330560) and [ZektorH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58816941/1330560) for their advice for devising the method to pass the array of dates to be available to the webapp javascript.

Link to the [webapp](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwOw9THlNShp9o1yrFw3FbtIfCcLMIuPsKN4khSuARp3lilNswQ/exec)

Link to the [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1shHxpM1maOuXdajI8Kwo-QzLtseeryt0c5QyHnfhv48/edit?usp=sharing)

Note: the script assumes that the user name is "user1". But there is a commented line (`var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername()`) that can be used to return the actual user and select dates based on that user.

The key things to note are:

- the basic code for `DataPicker exclusion` (in JavaScript.html) is that proposed by Amal
- this is wrapped in a `withSuccessHandler` that calls function `getuserdates()` (in code.gs) which returns the dates previously selected by the user.

**Comments on specific processes**

- `getuserdates()`
- `var datasheetData = datasheetRange.getDisplayValues();`: all the data is obtained at the outset:
- `datasheetRange.sort(6);` (Column F on a non-zero-based basis): the data is sorted by date to enable the output to be in date order:
- `var datanames = datasheetData.map(function(e){return e[2];});': the list of user names is extracted by using the Javascript [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method .`e[2]` will access Column C, or column 2 on a zero-based basis)
- `var userdates = [];`: a temporary array is setup to capture the previous dates
- `userdates.push('"' + datasheetData[i][5]+ '"');`: the script loops thought the user names, matches on the name of the user running the script, and extracts the relevant VL date(s) to the temporary array.
- `datasheetRange.sort(1);`: the spreadsheet data is resorted by Timestamp.
- `if (userdates.length !=0){`: the script tests whether or not any previous dates were captured.
- `userdates` look like this: `["11/11/2019", "11/15/2019", "11/16/2019", "11/17/2019", "11/24/2019"]`

**DatePicker**

- `minDate`: start date is 3 weeks from today: `"+3W"`
- `maxDate`: end date  is 12 weeks from today: `"+12W"`
- `beforeShowDay`: this is the datepicker parameter for exclusion of specific dates. The values `userdates` are returned from `getuserdates()`
- `$thisdate` defines a date format of m/d/y, and then
- `if ($.inArray($thisDate, userdates) == -1) {`: uses the JQuery [inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) method to test for the array date equal to the calendar date; if there is no match, it returns -1. So, when a match is made, the function returns "false" = 0 and the date is "greyed out/blurred" in the calendar.

---

**code.gs**

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function getuserdates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "VL Request";
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  // assume user name
  //var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername()
  var username = "user1";

  // set variables
  var datafirstrow = 2;
  var dataLR = datasheet.getLastRow();
  var dataLC = datasheet.getLastColumn();
  var datasheetRange = datasheet.getRange(datafirstrow,1, dataLR-datafirstrow+1, dataLC);
  //Logger.log(datasheetRange.getA1Notation());

  // sort the data by date
  datasheetRange.sort(6); // sort by Column F - VL date
  var datasheetData = datasheetRange.getDisplayValues();
  //Logger.log(datasheetData);

  //   get the user names as an array
  var datanames = datasheetData.map(function(e){return e[2];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
  //Logger.log(datanames); // DEBUG
  //Logger.log(datanames.length) // DEBUG

  // create an array to hold any dates
  var userdates = [];

  //  loop through the user names; test for equivalence to "username", and save VF date to an array
  for (var i=0;i<datanames.length;i++){
    //Logger.log("dataname = "+datanames[i])
    if (datanames[i] === username){
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i= "+i+", user name = "+datanames[i]+", VL date = "+datasheetData[i][5]);
      //userdates.push('"' + datasheetData[i][5]+ '"');
      userdates.push(datasheetData[i][5]);
    }
    else{
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i= "+i+" - no match");
    }
  }
  // resort the data by Timestamp
   datasheetRange.sort(1); // sort by Column A

  if (userdates.length !=0){
  //Logger.log("There are "+userdates.length+" previous dates for this user.");//DEBUG
  }
  else{
  //Logger.log("There no previous dates for this user");//DEBUG
  }

  //Logger.log(userdates);
  return userdates;
}
```

---

**JavaScript.html**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Tanaike - Pattern2
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/58811576/1330560
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(userdates => {
//console.log(userdates);
  $(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      minDate: "+3W", 
      maxDate: "+12W",
      beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        $thisDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray($thisDate, userdates) == -1) {
          return [true, ""];
        } else {
          return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }
      }
    });
  });
}).getuserdates();
</script>
```

---

**Page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="demo" >
    <h1>jQuery datepicker</h1>
     <p>click here : <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" /></p>
  </div>
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Stylesheet.html**

```
<style>
.demo { margin: 30px ; color : #AAA ; font-family : arial sans-serif ;font-size : 10pt } 
p { color : red ; font-size : 14pt } 
</style>
```